# MS Word change currently selected ribbon item using COM interface

Tags: python, windows, ms-word, com, ribbon

```
import comtypes.client as com

app=com.GetActiveObject('Word.Application')

app.Visible = True
app.Resize(400, 400)
```

Using this python script one can connect to opened MS Word document and resize it.

I need to programmatically change currently selected ribbon item. I need to emulate click on "File", "Home", "Insert", "Design" and so on. I am especially
 interested to open backstage view programmatically. Do you if there are such COM interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to automate the Ribbon interface in Office through the typical COM interfaces - there aren't any. This is by design, due to the previous CommandBars interface being "misused" by some developers to essentially disable the Office application. So the Ribbon doesn't expose any interactive interfaces for the developer.

It is possible, to a limited extend, to send keyboard commands, emulating the user's pressing an ALT key combination. But these combinations are not reliable - they can change dynamically, depending on the display language and what commands are currently visible in the Ribbon.

The only reliable interface is the Accessibility interface. That might serve your purpose. See, for instance, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb404170(v=office.12)

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the MS Word application and documents inside it via COM.

I haven't used `comtypes` and I would recommend that you consider `win32com` instead, because it will generate early-binding info from the COM interface that enables pop-up hints. I'm pretty sure `comtypes` doesn't do that.

Get to the application like this:

```
>>> from win32com.client import Dispatch
>>> mswApp = Dispatch('Word.Application')
```

This will give you access to the Application object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application.aspx)

One of this first things you will want is to control the active document

```
>>> doc = mswApp.ActiveDocument
```

Then you have access to the Document object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.document.aspx).

Judging from your question, you want your program to, in effect, press buttons in the Word application. That isn't quite how the COM object model works. Instead, you call methods and set properties of the Application and Document objects, so instead of pushing the buttons, you are calling the code that pressing the button inside the application would call. This works much the same as a VBA macro inside Word.